# GotFocus and LostFocus Events in WPF TextBox

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, binding

I have a textBox control in a WPF window. I have separate handlers for GotFocus and LostFocus events. But when the textbox attains focus for the first time LostFocus is invoked after GotFous (The textbox loses focus as soon as it attains focus for the first time) . But this doesn't happen when the textBox attains focus for the second time.

Comment: What are you doing in GotFocus?

Comment: Some text has been set in the textBox so i'm making the text to be empty. txtone.text=string.Empty;

Comment: I acetually have seen the same thing... the first time, it's GotFocus/LostFocus while subsequent times, it's LostFocus/GotFocus.  No idea why that is.  In my handlers I'm just logging to Console to see this.  I'm marking this as a favorite in case others have a solution/explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe something is happening during the GotFocus event handler (or deeper in the call stack) that is relinquishing focus to another control.

You might want to try setting a breakpoint in your LostFocus event handler and then look at the call stack to see if something is setting the focus elsewhere either directly or indirectly.